# How to cover this line of code contain java Annotation in unit testing using Jmock?

Tags: java

This code will retrive the data from database and it will match  the column name from which data is retrieve with annotate field name . How do I cover this lines of code in unit testing using jmock ? Please help me to out of this problem.

```
        ArrayList<String> criticalFields = getAllCriticalField("ORD", order
                .getSrcSysId());
        if (criticalFields != null && criticalFields.size() >= 1) {
            String query = "select * from  tvs.ORD where SRC_SYS_ID='"
                    + order.getSrcSysId() + "' AND ORD_ID='"
                    + order.getOrdId() + "'";
            connection = vwsUtil.getConnection();
            statement = connection.createStatement();

            Field[] fields = Order.class.getDeclaredFields();

            for (Field field : fields) {
                field.setAccessible(true);
                if (field.isAnnotationPresent(TableColumnAnnotation.class)) {
                    TableColumnAnnotation column = field
                            .getAnnotation(TableColumnAnnotation.class);
                    if (criticalFields.contains(column.columnName())) { 
                        if (column.columnName().equalsIgnoreCase(
                                "EST_RTS_DT")
                                || column.columnName().equalsIgnoreCase(
                                        "ACT_RTS_DT")
                                || column.columnName().equalsIgnoreCase(
                                        "CMIT_SHP_DT")
                                || column.columnName().equalsIgnoreCase(
                                        "ACT_FST_SHP_DT")
                                || column.columnName().equalsIgnoreCase(
                                        "ACT_FNL_SHP_DT")
                                || column.columnName().equalsIgnoreCase(
                                        "ORD_CANC_DT")
                                || column.columnName().equalsIgnoreCase(
                                        "SHP_BEF_DT")
                                || column.columnName().equalsIgnoreCase(
                                        "SHP_AFT_DT")) {

                            if (field.get(order) == null
                                    || field.get(order).toString()
                                            .isEmpty()) {
                                query = query + " AND "
                                        + column.columnName() + " IS NULL ";
                            } else {
                                Calendar cal = (Calendar) field.get(order);
                                java.util.Date dt = cal.getTime();
                                SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat(
                                        "dd-MM-yy");
                                String sqlDate = fmt.format(dt);
                                /*query = query + " AND "
                                        + column.columnName() + "='"
                                        + sqlDate + "'";*/
                                query = query + " AND "
                                        + column.columnName() + "=to_date('"
                                        + sqlDate + "','DD-MM-YY')";

                            }
                        } else if (column.columnName().equalsIgnoreCase(
                                "ORD_TS")
                                || column.columnName().equalsIgnoreCase(
                                        "ACK_TS")) {

                            if (field.get(order) == null
                                    || field.get(order).toString()
                                            .isEmpty()) {
                                query = query + " AND "
                                        + column.columnName() + " IS NULL ";
                            } else {
                                Calendar cal = (Calendar) field.get(order);
                                java.util.Date dt = cal.getTime();
                                SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat(
                                        "dd-MM-yy HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSSS");
                                String sqlDate = fmt.format(dt);
                                query = query + " AND "
                                        + column.columnName() + "='"
                                        + sqlDate + "'";
                                /*query = query + " AND "
                                        + column.columnName() + "=to_date('"
                                        + sqlDate + "','DD-MM-YY HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSSS')";*/

                            }
                        } else if (column.columnName().equalsIgnoreCase(
                                "DLR_MNG_TRNSP_IND")) {
                            if (field.get(order) == null
                                    || field.get(order).toString()
                                            .isEmpty()) {
                                query = query + " AND "
                                        + column.columnName() + " IS NULL ";
                            } else {
                                query = query + " AND "
                                        + column.columnName() + "="
                                        + field.get(order).toString();
                            }

                        } else {
                            if (field.get(order) == null
                                    || field.get(order).toString()
                                            .isEmpty()) {

                                query = query + " AND "
                                        + column.columnName() + " IS NULL ";
                            } else {
                                query = query + " AND "
                                        + column.columnName() + "='"
                                        + field.get(order).toString() + "'";

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            } //System.out.println("Order Query  =  "+query);
            resultSet = statement.executeQuery(query);

            if (!resultSet.next()) {System.out.println("Flag true  in Order   ");
                criticalFieldFlag = true;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Are you having problems with JMock in general or a certain part of your code is not being covered?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure specifically what problem you are having - but this code is going to be hard to understand and hard to unit test in its current form.

Your life is going to be a lot easy if you refactor this beast into distinct responsibilities.

The bulk of the code looks to be generating sql strings - that's one coarse responsibility that ought to be easy to test independently once it's been pulled out.

Once the sql generation is pulled out, testing its interaction with the database will be much easier.

Of course, to refactor safely you need tests.

The current structure of the code makes **unit** tests difficult to write. Before you start I'd therefore suggest you put a lot of **integration** test coverage in place - i.e tests that exercise this code and hit the database.